# Where's the path of compiled packages

Tags: debian, compiling, package-management, packaging

Where's the path of compiled packages from source on debian?

for example:

```
git clone git://github.com/lightspark/lightspark.git
cd lightspark
dpkg-buildpackage
[...long output...]
dpkg-buildpackage: full upload; Debian-native package (full source is included)
```

Then the packages is compiled successfully, but where the package (.deb) and source packages is located?

Comment: apparently is happening something wrong in the build process, after I run "dpkg-buildpackage", I did run "dpkg-deb -b debian/<package>" and .deb is generated to "debian/<package>.deb". Someone has idea what's happening wrong in the build process(I mean "dpkg-buildpackage") ?

Comment: You should not have to run more than one command for the entire build process. I recommend using `debuild -uc -us`. That's what I always use, and it takes care of a bunch of stuff for you. `debuild` is in the `devscripts` package.

Comment: I've used debuild also, but got same result, no .deb after compile.

Comment: Ok. Well, you'll have to give more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binary and source packages that are generated are written to the directory that is  one level above the top level source directory. In your case the top level source directory is `lightspark`, so it will be in the directory above `lightspark`. However, you could have easily discovered this by a look at some of the extensive Debian packaging documentation out there. The [Debian New Maintainer's Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/), for example.

Tip. When copying source, create a separate directory for each source package and then put the source in a subdirectory. E.g.

```
/usr/local/src/lightspark$ git clone git://github.com/lightspark/lightspark.git
```

Then the generated Debian packages will be in `/usr/local/src/lightspark`.

Comment: ok, but i can't see the packages in the lightspark folder, this the second debian package that i compile and cannot find the compiled packages.
the other that i've tried is awf (A Widget Factory)

Comment: @VictorAurélio: Please give more details of what procedure you followed, giving all relevant steps. You can update the question with these details. Then perhaps someone can tell you what you are doing wrong. BTW, it is directory, not folder.

Comment: @FaheemMitha why is it the `lightspark` directory? it should be the parent directory of the `lightspark` directory imo.

Comment: The steps that I followed is in the question, in both (awf and lightspark), cloned up the repository, changed the cwd with "cd"(to directory above 'debian', debian/..) and run "dpkg-buildpackage". Sorry for the 'folder' it's because I'm BR and translated 'pasta'->'folder', I'll try remember that's 'directory'

Comment: @UlrichDangel One level up from the lightspark directory. My answer was ambigious, rephrasing.

Comment: @VictorAurélio I think my answer may have been unclear - I've rephased - thanks to Ulrich for pointing this out. Can you confirm it is not in the directory above lightspark?

Comment: Yes, now I see these packages in 'lightspark/..' sorry for my confusion about directories.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know where to look for the documentation on something, a very useful tool on Linux if you want to see what files a process is dealing with, is `strace` (if you're on Solaris you can use `truss` in the same way) it writes its messages to stderr, which you can capture into a file:

```
$ strace -f dpkg-buildpackage 2> ../output
```

Then check the ../output file for entries like:

```
[pid  6545] creat("../lightspark_0.7.2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_amd64.deb", 0644) = 3
[pid  6552] creat("../lightspark-common_0.7.2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_amd64.deb", 0644) = 3
[pid  6559] creat("../browser-plugin-lightspark_0.7.2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_amd64.deb", 0644) = 3
[pid  6566] creat("../lightspark-dbg_0.7.2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_amd64.deb", 0644) = 3
```

which shows the files being created.
You can also look for 'open' calls:

```
$ grep "\.deb\"" ../output | grep "open" | grep -v ENOENT
...
[pid  6591] open("../lightspark_0.7.2-0ubuntu1~ppa1_amd64.deb", O_RDONLY) = 3
...
```